# Textbox cannot be empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am new at programming in c# in visual studio 2010. I have been trying to figure out When I click my save button my text boxes cannot be null or empty. I would appreciated if you guys could let me to a path in how to solve this.

Comment: The string class has a method that will help...

Answer (score 2):

You need to test the value of the text boxes (`.Text` property) to see if it is filled.

Using the `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` (.NET 4.0 and above) or `string.IsNullOrEmpty` methods in an `if` statement is a good start.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(aTextBox.Text))
{
  // it is not empty or null!
}
```